# Installing Ubuntu 15.10 on an old version (8.04)

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, updates, versions

I'm currently running on Ubuntu 8.04 but the original was 15.04. The tech guy installed the new one. 
Is it safe to install Ubuntu 15.10 with this? My computer has 2GB of RAM (I'll use the 32-bit maybe)

How can I install it safely? .
Which is better to use when installing: DVD or a Flash Drive
. Will be 8.04 still be there?

Comment: The way I read your question: I had Ubuntu 15.04 and then I downgraded to 8.10. Can I re-upgrade to 15.10. I have 2GB of RAM (Unsure about important info) PLEASE fix this so we can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were at one point already running Ubuntu 15.04 w/out any problems, then **yes**. You Should be able to run 15.10.

If the computer you are planning on installing supports 64 bit architecture then **USE IT**.

I prefer to use a USB Flash Drive when installing Ubuntu. If you think you want to try the USB method then check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) out. There might be more steps involved and it can be harder for a someone not familiar with this method.

If you want to use a DVD (Some people find this simple and easy to do) then all you need to do is download the Ubuntu 15.10 iso file and burn it to the DVD.

As far as the old version of Ubuntu still being there. It's honestly up to you. When you start to install the new version of Ubuntu, it will ask you how you want to install it. You can have the option to remove everything and only install Ubutnu 15.10 **OR** you can install it alongside the pre-existing version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @ravagingbacon - Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick